# Hiding element while preserving its space in page layout

Tags: codenameone

I'm making a list of containers programmatically. These containers have a table layout with two cells. In first cell I'm showing a checkbox and in second cell is a multibutton:

[image]

In some rows I would like disable user to click on a checkbox. I've tried using .setHidden(true), setVisible(true), etc.. on a checkbox but in that case checkbox is not visible(which is also acceptable) but in that case it is not preserving it's space and data in rows are not vertically aligned(as you see in the image). Does anyone know how to achieve this??? Graying and disabling the checkbox would be great, but not showing it and preserving it's space would be acceptable.

Here's the code:

```
    Container list = findContainerOrders(f);  
    list.setScrollableY(true);
    LinkedHashMap htJSONObject;

    //al is a ArrayList

    for(int i=0; i < al.size(); i++){

        htJSONObject = (LinkedHashMap)al.get(i);

        Container cr = new Container();

        TableLayout gr = new TableLayout(1, 2);

        gr.setGrowHorizontally(true);

        cr.setLayout(gr);
        final MultiButton b = new MultiButton();
        b.setName((String)htJSONObject.get("text1"));
        b.setTextLine1((String)htJSONObject.get("text2"));
        b.setTextLine2((String)htJSONObject.get("text3"));
        b.setTextLine3((String)htJSONObject.get("text4"));


        b.setUIIDLine1("MultiLine1");
        b.setUIIDLine2("MultiLine2");
        b.setUIIDLine3("MultiLine1Right");

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

            //some action here
        }

       });

        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.setName((String)htJSONObject.get("text1"));

        String sSomeCondition = (String)htJSONObject.get("Condition");

        //If this condition equals "NO" than I want to disable the checkbox
        if (sSomeCondition.equals("NO")) {

            // I've tried this but it doesn't work good
            //cb.setHidden(true);
            //cb.setHidden(true, true);
            //cb.setVisible(true);
            //cb.setEnabled(false);

            //TODO - disable checkbox code....???

        }
        else {
            cr.addComponent(cb);
        }

        cr.addComponent(b);

        list.addComponent(cr);                      
    }
```

When I use "setEnabled(false)" like Chen said in his answer, the checkbox is disabled but it's apperence is the same. I have a disabled style for my checkbox in my theme and I was able to change checkbox background but I want to change the color of the checkbox rectangle.

[image: changed background]

I tried to do that by adding constant "checkBoxUncheckDisImage" in a theme "Constants" tab and adding another image which would replace checkbox rectangle image but it didn't work.

[image]

How do I change the default checkbox image for a disabled checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

setEnabled(false) should do the trick, make sure you have a disabled style for the CheckBox in your theme

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried with setEnabled(false) but I would like to change apperence of the checkbox image. I have edited my question. Could you check it out please?